# How to make a CGRect animate

Tags: swift3, ios10

How can I create an animation like this one?

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
{

    let xPointRect = viewWithTag(1)?.alignmentRect(forFrame: rect).midX
    let yPointRect = viewWithTag(1)?.alignmentRect(forFrame: rect).midY
    let widthSize = self.viewWithTag(1)?.frame.size.width
    let heightSize = self.viewWithTag(1)?.frame.size.height
    let sizeRect = CGSize(width: widthSize! * 0.8, height: heightSize! * 0.4)

    let rectPlacementX = CGFloat(sizeRect.width/2)
    let rectPlacementY = CGFloat(sizeRect.height/2)
    let context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context2?.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context2?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context2?.move(to: CGPoint(x: (xPointRect! - rectPlacementX), y: (yPointRect! - rectPlacementY)))
    context2?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (xPointRect! + rectPlacementX), y: (yPointRect! + rectPlacementY)))
    context2?.setLineDash(phase: 3, lengths: dashArray)
    context2?.strokePath()


    context2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, 
        delay: 0, 
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.15, 
        initialSpringVelocity: 6.0, 
        options: .allowUserInteraction, 
        animations: { context2.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity },
        completion: nil)
}
```

My current code is not working because context2 doesn't contain a member .transfer since it is a CGRect.

How can I make this line animate? Any idea?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is this description enough?

Comment: No description has been added. What do you want to achieve? Do you animate line drawing?

Comment: Yes this is a line in my View. I want it to animate but I can't replace sideA_TextField with context2 because CGRect doesn't have a member .transform.

Comment: Edit your question and rephrase it. What exactly do you want to achieve? What have you tried? What is the issue you are running into? Afaics your question has nothing to do with `CGRect`.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

A `CGRect` is not visible, so I do not see why you want to animate it.

I assume what you want to animate the frame of a `UIView`.

You can change many properties of a `UIView` in an animation block. Also it's frame:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
someParentView.addSubview(view)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5) {
    someUIView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)

}
```

Comment: Hm, frame is not fully animatable in this way. To be precise, the bounds of the frame are not animatable, and are modified in the first instance of the animation process. But the origin of the frame does animate